# How to query on two aliases with AND condition in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to query multiple aliases and if the record is present in all the aliases, only then return the document.

But as per my understanding the search query uses OR condition internally to search multiple aliases using this URL:
`http://localhost:9200/my_alias_1,my_alias_2/_search`

Is there a way, where we can query on multiple aliases using a join or AND condition?

Comment: You could use _index field to determine in the caller code if it is a part of both the index or not. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank You Sahil Gupta . But can't we use alias similar to index?. There are multiple indices if _index field is used in the query, multiple indices needs to be passed right? Is there a way to do that or should i pass all the indices which needs to be searched?

Comment: You can use alias in the search query and a you need to look for the documents of the different indexes in the response. I don't think you need to paas index in the query